# Write a text file per image with same name in R

Tags: r, loop, text

In R I would like to create a text file for each picture I have in a folder and with the same name. By example:

```
Picture 1.png - Picture 1.txt

Picture 2.png - Picture 2.txt
```

But the text file name I got is  Picture 1.png.txt. How I can avoid to have the image extension in the text name ?

[image]

My program is the following

```
   folder <- "C:/Users/user/Desktop/R/test/" 

   jpeg <- list.files(folder) 

ind <- 0

for (k in jpeg){

  ind <- ind +1

  #Create matrix

  data <- matrix(nrow=1,ncol=5)

  data[1,1:5] <- cbind(a,b,c,d,e)

  filename <- paste(k, ".txt", sep=",")

  write.table(data, filename, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of functions in base R that do string processing.

For example with:

```
k = "/somewhere/something/file1.jpg"
```

you could chop off the last four characters to get the name of the file with no extension:

```
substr(k,1,nchar(k)-4)
## [1] "/somewhere/something/file1"
```

and then use `paste` to put `.txt` on it. Or you could substitute `.jpg` at the end of the path with `.txt`:

```
sub("\\.jpg$",".txt",k)
## [1] "file1.txt"
```

Note the use of `\\.` to match a real dot (otherwise dot matches any single character) an the use of `$` to anchor this match to the end of the path.

Also, this is not really GIS related and probably doesn't belong here, and has probably been well-answered on StackOverflow  (and elsewhere many times).